# Long press issue in apps in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have implemented comment box in xamarin for iOS and android app. The comment box works fine but if use long presses in the comment box the app is getting crashed.
Even if user doesn't put any comments and accidentally long press in the comment box still the app gets crashed.

Below is the code

```
<StackLayout Padding="20,1,20,1">
      <Editor AutomationId="txtGeneralCommentText" FontSize="Small" Completed="Editor_OnCompleted" HeightRequest="100" Text="{Binding ReadingCollection.GeneralComment.CommentText, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding ReadingCollection.IsGeneralCommentVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Editor>
    </StackLayout>
<Image AutomationId="imgGeneralCommentEmpty" Source="{ext:ImageResource 123.png}" IsVisible="{Binding ReadingCollection.GeneralComment.CommentText, Converter={StaticResource cnvImageCommentConverter}, ConverterParameter='Empty'}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ToggleGeneralCommentCommand}" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>
      <Image AutomationId="imgGeneralCommentFull"  Source="{ext:ImageResource 123.png}" IsVisible="{Binding ReadingCollection.GeneralComment.CommentText, Converter={StaticResource cnvImageCommentConverter}, ConverterParameter='Full'}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ToggleGeneralCommentCommand}" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>
```

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Do you mean the `Editor`?  I tried long pressing the editor in an iOS simulator and the app doesn't crash.

Comment: @Patrick Yes the Editor. One of our user is getting the issue. We have toggle functionality to visible/hide the Editor on click of image. Is that a problem ?

Comment: Does only one of your user get this issue? What's OS and version your user use?

Comment: @Rohit If it's something to do with the binding, try using a opaque `BoxView` to cover up the `Editor` or move the `Editor` away from the screen (use the `TranslateTo` method)  instead of using binding to set the `IsVisible` field of the `Editor`.

Comment: @Patrick Can you give us some example ? Its occurring on s7 with OS 7.0